# cancelling the broadcast of a receiving SMS doesn't work in the device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have a Broadcast Receiver in my application in which it invokes the `abortBroadcast()` method. So it cancels the broadcast of a receiving SMS and checks whether a specific content is available. If it is available application perform some tasks, otherwise `clearAbortBroadcast()` method is invoked to continue the broadcast of the SMS to the inbox. Also I have set a higher value as the priority in the manifest file.

I am using android 2.2 version for developing the application. Everything is working fine with the emulator and it provides the expected results for me. But when I test the application in the phone which has `4.0.4 version (ICS)`, it doesn't work. Message broadcast cancellation is not happening and every receiving SMS which contains the specific content reaches the inbox as a normal SMS does.

P.S : Everything works fine with the emulator. I have set the priority as high as "999999". All the permissions have been included.

Here is the code snippet.

```
public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   this.abortBroadcast();

   final String pinNumber = "abcd";
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
   String smsMsg = "";
   String replyPhoneNum = "";

   if(bundle != null)
   {
       Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
       msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

       for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
       {
           msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
           smsMsg += "SMS From " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
           smsMsg += "\n";
           smsMsg += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
           smsMsg += "\n";
           replyPhoneNum = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
       }
   }

   if(smsMsg.contains("SecretCode: "+pin+"\n"))
   {

       String[] splitMsg = smsMsg.split("\\n");
       String[] splitFeatures;

       Bundle b = new Bundle();
       splitMsg = smsMsg.split("\\n");

       for(int i=0; i<splitMsg.length; i++)
       {
          if(!(splitMsg[i].equalsIgnoreCase("null")))
          {
           splitFeatures = splitMsg[i].split(":");             

           if(splitFeatures[0].equals("Contact Number"))
           {
               String contactName = splitFeatures[1];
               b.putString("contactname", contactName);     
           }         

          }

          if(splitMsg[i].contains("email"))
          {
              String email = "email";
              b.putString("email", email);
          }
       }

       b.putString("replyPhoneNum", replyPhoneNum);

       Intent i = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       i.putExtras(b);
       context.startActivity(i);

   } 
   else
   {
       this.clearAbortBroadcast();
   }

}
   }
```

In the android manifest file,

```
  <receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
     <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

That's it. All other permissions have been used correctly. This works fine in the emulator. But not working in the device.

Comment: post the code for your receiver

Comment: does you reciever code get called at all (on ICS) ? what are you registering your reciever on ?

Comment: @FoamyGuy : I have posted the code I used.

Comment: @Oren on ICS it is not happening. Receiving SMS directly goes to the SMS inbox.

Comment: You have made sure there are no other third party SMS apps on the device?  Handcent, for example, will intercept with higher priority than you.

Comment: @iagreen don't have any of those installed in my device.